# Is there a way to generate combinations, one at a time?

Tags: python, combinations

I can generate combinations from a list of numbers using itertools.combinations, such as the following:

```
from itertools import combinations

l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

for i in combinations(l,2):
    print(list(i))
```

This generates the following:

```
[1, 2]
[1, 3]
[1, 4]
[1, 5]
[2, 3]
[2, 4]
[2, 5]
[3, 4]
[3, 5]
[4, 5]
```

How can I generate just one of these list pairs at a time and save it to a variable?  I want to use each pair of numbers, one pair at a time, and then go to the next pair of numbers.  I don't want to generate all of them at once.

Comment: This is already what you are doing. You generate one at a time in your loop. Just perform your expected computation inside the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `itertools` library actually returns a generator for most of it's functions (including `itertools.combinations()`). You can read more about Generators [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators). Basically, it's a function that lazily calculates values instead of generating everything all at once.

You can just get a single value out of a generator using the `next` command. Take a look at the following snippet:

```
import itertools

l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

comb_generator = itertools.combinations(l, 2)

temp = next(comb_generator)  #Get the first combo into a var
print(temp)

#Do some other stuff

temp = next(comb_generator)  #Get another combo
print(temp)
```

Whenever you want a new combination, you can get it by calling `next()` on your generator.

Comment: This solution worked perfectly.  I wasn't aware of Generators, and this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Is there a way to skip a bunch of values instead of going one by one with the next(comb_generator) command?  For example, can you skip 5 values to save processing time?

Comment: The main selling point of generators is that the implementation of how the generation is done is hidden from you. Which means that you really don't have control of what order they're returned in (at least for `itertools`). What exactly are you trying to accomplish? You might need a different approach